# How can I perform a subtraction dynamically without the need to resort to a button event?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to perform a subtraction, where when entering the values, the operation is performed automatically without the need to click on a button

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Importe que realizara al ticket</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="" value="{{this._usuario.TotalImporte}}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Importe/código total del ticket</ion-label>
  <ion-input disabled type="text" name="num2" placeholder="" value="{{this._usuario.TotalImporte}}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Saldo a Facturar</ion-label>
  <ion-input disabled type="text" name="sum" placeholder=""></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I attached an image of what I already have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Two-way binding **[(ngModel)]**

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Importe que realizara al ticket</ion-label>
      <ion-input  type="text" name="num1" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="this._usuario.TotalImporte" value="{{this._usuario.TotalImporte}}" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Importe/código total del ticket</ion-label>
      <ion-input disabled type="text" name="num2" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="this._usuario.TotalImporte"  value="{{this._usuario.TotalImporte}}" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Saldo a Facturar</ion-label>
      <ion-input disabled type="text" name="sum" [value]= "this._usuario.TotalImporte - this._usuario.TotalImporte" placeholder="" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

**Working demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-icvos9